# Error in simple file handling C program

Tags: c, file-io

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    fp=fopen("DATA","w");
    for(i=1;i<=30;++i)
        putw(i,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("DATA","r");
    while((i=getw(fp))!=EOF)
        printf("%4d",i);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get the expected output. The program prints the number till 25 rather than till 30. If I set `i<=20`, I get the right output. I do not understand this.

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explicitly post the contents of the file, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: Is there any special reason you are using the obscure `putw` and `getw` functions.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Those are the functions mentioned in the textbook I follow. Are there some other functions which are used for such tasks?

Comment: I am not sure about it. But you can printout return value of putw to check whether writes are successful or not. You can also set error indicators on stream , if there is any error.   Reference : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/putw.html   http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/getw.html

Comment: @PranavArora Look under "APPLICATION USAGE" in the [docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/putw.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII 26 is the [Ctrl-Z (aka SUB) character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z) that on some systems is used to indicate the end of file (normally only for text files). This is the reason your program stops reading the file as soon as it sees the value 26.

The reason this becomes an issue is that you're opening the file in text mode, yet are storing binary data in it (using `putw()` and `getw()`).

To fix this, open the file in binary mode and try again.

Comment: @PranavArora: Second argument to `fopen()`

Comment: I replaced `fp=fopen("DATA","r");` with `fp=fopen("DATA","rb");` and got a really weird output. Here is a screenshot: http://i61.tinypic.com/zx1zzc.png

Comment: @PranavArora: Did you change both `fopen()` calls?

Comment: Oops, sorry, now it shows the correct output. Thanks but I still do not see how ASCII code comes into the scene.

Comment: @PranavArora: The takeaway message is that if you're reading/writing binary data, you should open the file in binary mode. Otherwise all sorts of weird things can happen.

Comment: But why should I use the binary mode?

Comment: @PranavArora: Because `putw()` and `getw()` work with binary values. Read up on differences between binary and text files (Google is your friend here).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by user NPE you work with the binary files in binary mode only.
Here ASCII code comes into the picture because when you are saving an integer to file it is actually stored as sequence of 4 bytes.
If you open your generated DATA file in any hex editor you will notice that when you saved i as 1 into the file it is actually stored as

```
01 00 00 00
```

or

```
00 00 00 01
```

according to the endian-ness of your system.

On the same basis when you save 26, it gets actually saved as

```
26 00 00 00
```

or

```
00 00 00 26
```

But when you read this file in text mode and not binary mode, then if character 26 is encountered it is treated as EOF and getw returns -1.

I hope this explains you the actual problem.

This will not happen if you open and close your file in binary mode and write bytes to your file.